# Pen writes faint

Tags: stationery

Whenever I use a new ball pen it works fine and writes darker.But after one day it starts writing very light.I have changed many pen but same thing happens.Why this happens to me every time?? [image]

Comment: This isn't a question that seeks a lifehack.  Or are you asking how to prevent pens from doing this?

Comment: @Chenmunka I didn't understand

Comment: The picture helps. I can see what you are describing. What is the brand name of the pen? Is this a "gel" ink pen?

Comment: Maybe it's just dried up a lot when you first write with the pen. Once the 'fresh' ink flows, you get the proper shade. See [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/fountainpens/comments/34s59i/why_does_ink_write_darkerwetter_after_sitting_in/) about the reverse in a discussion about fountain pen ink: when the ink is dryer there's less water, making it darker. But ... what's the lifehack you're looking for?

Answer (score 4):

You say it happens evey time with a new pen (I assume you mean regardless of the brand). From what I can see you are applying quite a lot of pressure when writing.  I don't know if it is possible, but perhaps this excessive pressure may cause deformation of the point where the ball gets imbedded deeper within the socket, resulting in less ink passing through. You could get a new pen, try applying a bit less pressure when writing, and see if anything changes.

Comment: +1 While it's difficult to distort the point if not impossible, I agree with your problem analysis—too much pressure bearing down on the pen. Excessive pressure can push the ball into the socket deeply enough to restrict full flow of new ink around the ball tip. The tip-off for this answer is the appearance of deep grooves on the back of the page in the picture. Nice problem analysis!

Answer (score 0):

When my pens start doing that I try the following, in this order:

- Write squiggly lines on scrap until the ink starts to flow properly again.  Sometimes ink dries on the ball, this is a way to remove it.
- Hold the pen by the end opposite the tip.  Twist your wrist back and forth swiftly;  the goal is to force the ink down towards the tip using centripetal force.
- On SOME kinds of pens, you can blow into the back of the ink reservoir;  same goal, force the ink towards the tip, but using pressure this time.
- Last option:  use safety!  I will apply a lighter or match flame to the metal tip of the pen for a few seconds.  Be careful not to melt any plastic.  This one is particularly useful if the ball gets deformed and stuck, such that it cannot roll.  The heat will expand the outer casing of the ball-point, allowing the ball to roll again.  If the ball is TOO deformed, this will only work temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Notice if all the pens you used had a hole at back or not (or any ventilation)?
If all of them had no ventilation, the possible reason for fading may be creation of vacuum due to no air passage.
As the pen writes, ink empties in refill creating a vacuum.